# Bokeh, Python: Dashed line becomes solid when zooming in

Tags: python, bokeh, line-plot

I'm plotting two lines, one solid, one dashed. At the initial zoom the lines appear as defined. However, when zooming into the plot the dashed line becomes solid. The pictures below illustrate the problem. Here is the code that defines the lines:

```
turbidity_stn3_plot1 = f.line(x='Datetime',y='Turbidity', y_range_name='default', color='olive',line_color='black', line_dash=[1,10], line_width=1, source=turbidity_stn_03_plot_01_source)
turbidity_stn1_plot1 = f.line(x='Datetime',y='Turbidity', y_range_name='default', color='olive',line_color='black', line_dash='solid', source=turbidity_stn_01_plot_01_source)
```

I already tried different 'line_dash' values, like 'dashed' and 'dotted' with the same result.

I noticed that, when increasing the distance between dashes (e.g. 'line_dash=[1,20]'), the closer I can zoom in before the line turns solid.

Does anybody know why this is and how to avoid it?

Should I report this as a bug on [Bokeh Github](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues)?

[image: Dashed line zoomed out (y-axis 0 to 40)]

[image: Dashed line zoomed in(y-axis 0 to 35)]

Comment: Definitely report it, however I am not able to reproduce anything like what you describe, so you will need to provide *all* the information asked for in the GH issue template.

Comment: Thanks Bigreddot. I opened a new issue on Github
 [here](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/6007).

Answer (score 1):

This is a result of browser-dependent behavior of HTML canvas implementations. There is nothing that the Bokeh project can do about it (which is why the GH issue was eventually closed). If you are working in regimes where this issue shows up, the only alternative is to use other visual properties, e.g. width or color, instead of dashing.